# Value showing up as null even though I assigned value in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I'm trying to do some sort of conditional statement to calculate a value. To mock my data I am assigning the value in my controller (temporarily) to see how my UI is coming along. I can perform the calculation in a function block in the view, but it's lengthy and doesn't belong there. So, I am trying now to do the calculation in a model (`Calculations.cs`).

The code for the calculation is working in that a value is being passed, except that my condition is failing and passing the default value of `0` when it should be passing another value based on my mocked value in the controller.

Here is the `Calculations.cs`

```
public class Calculations
{
    PriceQuote price = new PriceQuote();
    StepFilingInformation filing = new StepFilingInformation();
    public decimal Chapter7Calculation
    {
        get
        {
            return
                price.priceChapter7
                +
                ((ReferenceEquals
                    (filing.PaymentPlanRadioButton,
                    Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes))
                ?
                price.pricePaymentPlanChapter7
                :
                0);
        }

    }
}
```

I originally had `(filing.PaymentPlanRadioButton == Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes)` checking whether or not the radio button was set to "Yes", but changed it to `ReferenceEquals`. This doesn't affect the outcome.

I have my controller assigning the value to `PaymentPlanRadioButton` to "Yes", so `pricePaymentPlanChapter7` should be the value being added to `priceChapter7`, but it is not. Instead "0" is being added as the fall back to the condition.  So `PaymentPlanRadioButton` is null even though I am assigning it in the controller.

I cannot figure out how to fix this. If I assign it in the model and get it to work that will not resolve the issue as when I remove the mocking controller and expect a user to choose a radio button it will still be `null` and the condition will fail.

Here is the "mock" controller:

```
public class QuoteMailerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult EMailQuote()
    {
        Calculations calc = new Calculations();
        var total = calc.Chapter7Calculation;

        QuoteData quoteData = new QuoteData
        {
            StepFilingInformation = new Models.StepFilingInformation
            {
                //"No" is commented out, so "Yes" is assigned
                //PaymentPlanRadioButton = 
                    //Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.No,
                PaymentPlanRadioButton = 
                    Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes,
            }
         };
    }
}
```

And this is where I store prices (`PriceQuote.cs`):

```
public class PriceQuote
{
    public decimal priceChapter7 { get { return 799; } }
    public decimal pricePaymentPlanChapter7 { get { return 100; } }
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class QuoteData
{
    public PriceQuote priceQuote;
    public Calculations calculations;
    public StepFilingInformation stepFilingInformation { get; set; }
    public QuoteData()
    {
        PriceQuote = new PriceQuote();
        Calculations = new Calculations();
    }
}
```

So, the way this should work is 799 + 100 = 899, since `PaymentPlan.Yes` is assigned as the value to the radio button in the controller. But instead I am getting just 799 (799 + 0) because when I debug `PaymentPlanRadioButton` is coming up null.

Any thoughts/guidance?

Just in case, here is the `PaymentPlanRadioButton` located within `StepFilingInformation.cs` (and is one of my models):

```
public enum PaymentPlan
{
    No,
    Yes
}
public class PaymentPlanSelectorAttribute : SelectorAttribute
{
    public override IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
    {
        return Selector.GetItemsFromEnum<PaymentPlan>();
    }
}       
[PaymentPlanSelector(BulkSelectionThreshold = 3)]
public PaymentPlan? PaymentPlanRadioButton { get; set; }
```

Sorry for the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Calculations class bases it's math on the StepFilingInformation object it contains. However, you never set StepFilingInformation from within Calculations to anything other than a new, empty object.

Your constructor should probably require a parameter of type StepFilingInformation.

```
public class Calculations
{
    StepFilingInformation filing;
    public Calculations(StepFilingInformation filing)
    {
       this.filing = filing;
    }
```

Regardless of how you pass your calculations class a reference to StepFilingInformation, you must set this value **before** you run your calculation that depends on it.

Also if QuoteData is your ViewModel, then it shouldn't contain a reference to your Calculations class. It should only contains results created in the calculations class that the View must display.

```
StepFilingInformation filing = new Models.StepFilingInformation
{
    PaymentPlanRadioButton = Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes,
};

Calculations calc = new Calculations(filing);
var total = calc.Chapter7Calculation;

QuoteData quoteData = new QuoteData //Only include Properties you're going to display in the view model
{
    Total = total
};
```

Comment: That last code block is what's in my controller. So the `StepFilingInformation filing....` (first 4 lines of second block) is actually within `QuoteData quoteData = new QuoteData...` in my mock controller.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Your mock controller creates an instance of calculation class, computes the total without ever setting filing with the calculation class, then sets a second instance of filing that has the correct data within QuoteData after the calculation is over.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I was trying the `Calculations` and `var total` at the end after `QuoteData quoteData` but that wasn't working. In any event the real problem was that I had `StepFilingInformation` inside `QuoteData`.  Ok, but now, where did you get `Total = total` from, because VS is complaining that `QuoteData` doesn't contain a definition for "Total"?

Comment: That was just an example of what I'd probably put in your ViewModel. My point was just that the classes you currently have in your ViewModel I don't believe belong there. In my example Total would be a decimal property in QuoteData (because if you're calculating the total in that action, presumably you want to display it).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the insight/help